# Verb for coming into contact with another using one's shoulder

Tags: single-word-requests, sports

I would like to phrase the action of 'hitting' someone with one's shoulder, perhaps in a single word. Disappointingly, [*shoulder*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shoulder) is already an actively used verb for a different action entirely:

> **shoul·dered, shoul·der·ing, shoul·ders**
>   v.tr.
>    1. To carry or place (a burden, for example) on the shoulders.
>    2. To take on; assume: shouldered the blame for his friends.
>    3. To push or apply force to, with or as if with the shoulder.
>    4. To make (one's way) by or as if by shoving obstacles with one's shoulders.
>
> *(Source: The Free Dictionary)*

I will give out even higher praise for a solution that incorporates the specific aspect of coming into contact with the 'shouldered' person's teeth. It does not have to be a single word, although I would appreciate a concise phrase.

Comment: I'd just say I bumped into them.

Comment: So ideally, you’re looking for a sports-related word that means _hitting another player’s teeth with your shoulder_? I doubt such a specific term exists. Senses 3 and 4 in your dictionary quotes are not far off, though—if the context is sports, I would see nothing strange about “He shouldered his opponent”.

Comment: You might get away with [barge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/barge?q=barge) (see Verb 1.2 at that link).

Comment: _Georgioed_ ? :)

Comment: My problem with 'to shoulder' is that it carries positive connotations that I would rather not inadvertently give in my situation

Comment: If there were such a word, may I suggest "to Suarez" as the antonym?

Comment: @Spork Shouldering someone in the face definitely does not have positive connotations. It is the shoulder-based equivalent of kneeing, elbowing, or headbutting someone, all of which are quite aggressive and definitely violent actions. If you meant _inadvertently_ bumping into someone with your shoulder, i.e., with no real negative connotations, then _shoulder_ would not be a good word to use.

Comment: @Spork, since you are interested in less positive connotations,I'd suggest military terminology.  You could search for contact with pouldron, or pauldron (armor for the protection of the shoulders)

Comment: Are you Uruguayan by chance? :)

Comment: In England we call it a foul. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to suggest **shoulder-barge**, but it seems that is slang. So instead, how about...

> [**Shoulder-Charge**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shoulder-charge)
>
> Defn: Charge at (a person or obstacle) with the shoulder first
>
> e.g. She *shoulder-charged* the door, and found herself in a moonlit
> room

Although it probably implies something more like this...

[image]

than this...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The term for a shoulder thrust or shoulder-to-shoulder contact in [wrestling](http://www.lakeparkwrestling.com/resources-glossary.cfm) but not a hit *per se* is allegedly according to the Lake Park Wrestling website:

> *Cut back* — In the bottom or down position, a wrestler turns their inside shoulder and head under the opponent's near shoulder.
>
> *Square* — This is the term used to describe how you would position your shoulders/body to be parallel to your opponent’s while you are in the neutral position. This is done to prevent him from being able to create angles on you.